# Sort by group key

Tags: sql-order-by, apache-superset

How can sort grouped data by a key field while creating a slice in superset?

In a dropdown I see only metrics to sort by, no key field presented.

[image]

Comment: Which version of superset are you on, and which type of visualization are you using?

Comment: If you are visualizing as a Table, you can click on the column name to sort by the column you grouped by.